# ionic 2 - item slider - slide to trigger function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have ionic-item-sliding directives with 3 buttons. 2 (A and B) Appear when I slide left and 1 (button C) on the right.

I want to implement the behavior that the function under button C is triggered when I really drag the item to the far right.

The docs on ionic2 hompage give this code snippet as example

```
ondrag(event, item) {
  let percent = event.getSlidingPercent();
  if (percent > 0) {
    // positive
    console.log('right side');
  } else {
    // negative
    console.log('left side');
  }
  if (Math.abs(percent) > 1) {
        this.navCtrl.push(NextPage,{param:item},{ animate: true, direction: 'forward' })
  }
}
```

using it on

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items "(ionDrag)="ondrag($event, item)"></ion-item-sliding>
```

I've getting the behaviour that when I swipe too far, it will call and push the page multiple times (i guess as many events as i'm throwing)

Any suggestions on how to implement this correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a flag to be sure the `push()` method is executed only once.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { Page1 } from 'page1.ts';

@Component({
     templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  private alreadyPushed: boolean;

  private items: Array<any>;

  private selectedItem: any;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.items = [
      'City of Amsterdam',
      'City of Bogota',
      'City of Buenos Aires',
      'City of Dhaka'
    ];
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    // Initialize the flag
    this.alreadyPushed = false;

    if(this.selectedItem) {
      // Reset the selected item
      this.selectedItem._setOpenAmount(0);
    }

  }

  ondrag(event, item) {
    let percent = event.getSlidingPercent();
    if (percent > 1 && !this.alreadyPushed) {

      // Store the event to reset it later
      this.selectedItem = event;

      // Set the flag to true
      this.alreadyPushed = true;

      // Push the new page
      this.navCtrl.push(Page1, { param : item });
    }
  }
}
```

Also please notice that you should use `percent > 1` instead of `Math.abs(percent) > 1` so you only push the page when sliding to the right.

Comment: thanks for the reply, one issue is, that when the page gets popped the item remains "slided". Is there a way to reset the positions?

Comment: I've updated both the answer and the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hHKUIq?p=preview), now it resets the item when going back to the view :)

Comment: Hi, sorry forgot to confim, yes thanks a lot! I'll be using ionViewDidLeave()

Comment: Glad to hear that :)